# VSCode terminal not showing icons on terminal on ZSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

As shown in the picture below, my terminal in VS Code is showing is showing missing icons, whereas it's totally fine in my external terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use the same font in your VS Code terminal as you do in your external terminal. In VS Code, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to open settings, then search for **Terminal › Integrated: Font Family.**

Comment: it worked changed my font to "meslolgs nf"

Answer (score 1):

it worked, also i have to make change to my font to "meslolgs nf"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy8fU.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Adding the same font used in the MacOS terminal into VSCode solved the problem.

[image]

VS Code settings (Search - terminal font)

[image]

After saving the change

[image]